# lamp php ubuntu 10.04 with cgi I get accesses to '/var/www/...' instead of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/...'

Tags: php, apache-2.2, cgi, lamp

I have a basic php cgi configuration problem on top of the apache web server in Ubuntu 10.04 . I am trying to setup cgi so as to answer one of the urls `localhost/cgi-bin/index.php` or `localhost/index.php` with the output from the execution of `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.php` which currently has as output `phpinfo()` .

I followed [Ubuntu 10.04 > Ubuntu Server Guide > Web Servers > HTTPD - Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html) to get me started and have the virtual host stuff done . I also created the php script and tried to access it but I have the force redirect problem . I tried to fix it by enabling mod_actions and doing [what the page says about the Action and AddHandler directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.force-redirect.php). I inserted the 2 directives in `httpd.conf` but I get accesses to `/var/www` in the error log:

```
Action php-script /cgi-bin/php # (or /cgi-bin , /cgi-bin/ for my setup)
AddHandler php-script .php
```

So now I am stuck and I could use some help.

Comment: Are you trying to run PHP scripts using CGI methods? It'd be far more efficient to use the in-server PHP module instead. CGI scripts were all the rage years ago, but only because language interpreters were NOT embedded inside the webserver. It's definitely a slower method than in-server processing.

Comment: I thinck I'll settle for a way to do what I want to do : get 'localhost/index.php' to be answered by '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.php' at first and go on from there , since I have a school project to do that won't be deployed in production that I need done , and I also have a mapserver cgi that I have to figure out how to use later so cgi is the way to go I guess .